# I am downloading two files using flask , How to stop downloading duplicate file

Tags: python, pandas, flask, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

**I coded for downloading file in flask. I am getting downloaded file with duplication **

My code is below not exact.

```
file_path="c:/user/Download"
With pd.excelwriter(file_path) as writer:
     data1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="something")
     data2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="something 2")
return send_file(file_path, as_attachement=True)
```

So here I am returning one download file and another file from excelwriter.

How to avoid one duplicate file
Note: send_file return must needed.

Download file like this
A.xlsx
A(1).xlsx

I want only one file

Comment: Can you post some more of your code? What does `send_file` do? My assumption is that's what is causing the error. Also, what are `data1` and `data2`?

Comment: data1 and data2 are the data frames, send_file do download file

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are trying to write two different pandas data frames to the same workbook, each with it's own sheet.

To do that

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  

    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```

[source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

With this, the full excel file path is what is opened as the `writer`. It looks like you are using the directory `file_path="c:/user/Download"`. It should be something like `file_path="c:/user/Download/AFile.xlsx"`

The same would go for `send_file()`. You are sending the directory, rather than just one file.

Comment: That is correct, but my problem was in ExcelWriter it returns one download file and another download file return with send_file. I need only send_file return download file ,

Comment: @Rudraprakash your file path being send to `sendfile()` is still a directory, not a single file